# Node.js/Express - Code inside callback is running after completing the first function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm making on app for camps where user can come and create their camping experience and comments over it. I try to remove first if any camps there in mongodb, after that to make 3 dummy camps data and then associate comments on it. but it seems always all 3 camps creating first and then comments because of that comments can't be associated with them.

```
Campground.remove({}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('some error in campground');
    }
    campdata.forEach(function (seed) {
        Campground.create(seed, function (err, createdData) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('camps not created');
            } else {
                // create comments
                Comment.create({
                    description: 'this is the best place but wish if there is internet',
                    author: 'satty'
                }, function (err, commentdata) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        createdData.comments.push(commentdata);
                        createdData.save();
                        console.log(commentdata);
                    }
                });
                console.log(createdData);
            } //else completed
        }); // campground create completed
    }); // for each
    console.log('removed campgrounds');
}); // campground remove
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Node is asynchronous. `forEach` runs synchronously, but the functions within are asynchronous — meaning that they are still executing *after* the `forEach` loop completes. This is a problem for you because the iterator on `forEach` has already reached the last element in the array long before the asynchronous comment-adding function executes.

One way to solve this is to use [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async):

(Removed superfluous code for brevity)

```
let async = require('async')

Campground.remove({}, function(err) {
    async.each(campdata, function(seed, callback) {
        Campground.create(seed, function(err, createdData) {
            let comment = {
                description: 'this is the best place but wish if there is internet',
                author: 'satty'
            }
            Comment.create(comment, function(err, commentdata) {
                createdData.comments.push(commentdata)
                createdData.save()
                callback(err)
            })
        })
    }, function(err) {
        // all done!
    })
})
```